# How to use JSDoc to document a Vue component with script setup?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jsdoc, vue-composition-api

I'm building a Vue library with TypeScript. I'd like to export the documentation of the components, like I do with ordinary functions.

Previously we would do this:

```
<script>
/**
 * This is the documentation of my component.
 */
export default {
}
</script>

<template></template>
```

But now with `script setup`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template></template>
```

How do we document the component?

Comment: You could use the same syntax no? It's still commented-out'ed out or I'm mistaken? Never used JSdoc.

Comment: @kissu No, because there is no `export default` with `script setup`.

Comment: JSdoc needs it absolutely? Couldn't it read the JS directly, without the `export`?

Comment: @kissu I'm building a TypeScript library which exports a component. I need the JSDoc to be correctly exported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `<script setup>` you can't use JSDoc on the component export.

It's a compiler syntaxic sugar that gets out the export of the setup function, so you obviously can't comment a function that is "generated" by the compiler.

If you really needs JSDoc, you should use a regular `<script>` with a default export :)

```html
<script>
/** This is my nice component documentation */
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup() {
    // your code
  }, 
}
</script>
```

Also works with the typescript `defineComponent` wrapper:

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

/** This is my nice component documentation */
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup() {
    // your code
  }
})
</script>
```

EDIT: as mentionned by @EstusFlask in the comments, you can mix both `<script setup>` and `<script>` on a SFC component (see [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script))
So you can use the regular script to expose your JSDoc.

```html
<script setup>
// component setup. Takes priority over the eventual `setup()` function of the export object in <script>.
</script>

<script>
/** This is my nice component documentation */
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but my vscode intellisense still can't pull it up. Probably a nuxt3 environment issue or vscode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for my needs for typedoc. However, I do notice a different in the `<script>` portion between your update and @EstusFlask's answer: in your update, the export is not entirely empty; in @EstusFlask's answer, the export is an empty object. Which is the right one, and/or what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003725/18059097 or I would, but it seems you don't even need to put anything in the default export, so you can simply do

```
<script>
/**
 * This is my well documented component
 */
export default {};
</script>
<script setup>
// your code
</script
```

Using this style can also be advantageous so that you have a way to use the editor's Go To References feature, though it's a bit of a silly workaround.

Another slightly different idea is to create a separate file `index.js` and do

```
import { default as MyComponentVue } from './MyComponent.vue';

/**
 * This is my well documented component.
 */
export const MyComponent = MyComponentVue;
```

This of course has the downside of the documentation being in a separate file though.

Comment: It makes sense, however it doesn't seem to work for some reason